# How to show a div once after every certain interval of time

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, setinterval

I am creating a user greeting msg which greets the user with a msg like Good Morning, Good Afternoon and Good evening based on the time.. Everything works fine but I want to know how can I hide the message after showing once until the day time changes, and show the message again as the day time with message changes.

For example, when you first open the website in the morning, it will greet you with Good morning message only once and then do not show this greeting message every time you refresh the page until the next part of the day starts like afternoon or evening and vice-versa.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think using `localstorage` / `cookie` for this would be useful. You could save the time/date of the last greeting displayed.

Comment: Can you help me with the code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You Can Do this Using Simple **LocalStorage** (for Manintaining Last Message Displayed History) and *Date Time Comparison* in **Javascript**

```
<script>
    setInterval(greet , 1000*60);
    function greet(){

        var date = new Date();
        try{
            if(!localStorage.lastGreeted || !localStorage.lastGreetedPeriod)
                greetWithMessage(date);
            else if(getDate(localStorage.lastGreeted)!=getDate(date))
                greetWithMessage(date);
            else if(divideDayTime(date.getHours())!=localStorage.lastGreetedPeriod)
                greetWithMessage(date);
        }
        catch(err){

             greetWithMessage(date);
        }

    }



    function getDate(obj){
        if(!(obj instanceof Date) )
            obj = new Date(obj);
        return obj.getDate()+'-'+(1+obj.getMonth())+'-'+obj.getFullYear();
    }

    function divideDayTime(hours){
     //Update Message and It's Period Here 
        if(hours<12)
            return 'MORNING';
        else if(hours>=12 && hours <=16)
            return 'AFTERNOON';
        else if(hours>16 && hours<=20)
            return "EVENING";
        else 
            return "NIGHT";

    }
    function greetWithMessage(d){
        localStorage.lastGreeted=d;
        var message = localStorage.lastGreetedPeriod=divideDayTime(d.getHours());

        alert("Good "+ message);
    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a modal for this to display the Greeting whenever the user visits the platform. Store the last log-in time in cookies and access that every time they login and provide them with an appropriate greeting.